# how to deserialize json object and add response to arraylist

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I am creating an app using soundcloud api but I am getting error while parsing json object, I am new in this things so don't know what I am doing wrong here

Here is my interface

**ScService.java**

```
public interface SCService
{
    @GET("/resolve.json?url=https://m.soundcloud.com/kshmr/sets/materia&client_id=iZIs9mchVcX5lhVRyQGGAYlNPVldzAoX")
    Call<Track> getTrack();
}
```

Here is my model class

**Track.java**

```
public class Track
{   
    @SerializedName("title")
    private String mTitle;

    @SerializedName("stream_url")
    private String mStreamUrl;

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public String getStreamUrl()
    {
        return mStreamUrl;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Config.API_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

SCService Scservice = retrofit.create(SCService.class);
Call<Track> call = Scservice.getTrack();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Track>(){

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Track> call, Response<Track> response)
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
                if(response.isSuccessful())
                {
                //String track = response.body().toString();
                //Log.e("jsonres",track);

                //gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                gson = new Gson();
                Track track = gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(), Track.class);
          }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call p1, Throwable p2)
        {
            // TODO: Implement this method
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the JSON response from api callcall

```
enter code here
 {"kind":"track","id":399448641,"created_at":"2018/02/14 11:40:02 +0000","user_id":319295181,"duration":188726,"commentable":true,"state":"finished","original_content_size":33279566,"last_modified":"2018/03/10 17:33:18 +0000","sharing":"public","tag_list":"KSHMR \"House of Cards\" \"Sidnie Tipton\" Dharma \"Spinnin' \"","permalink":"houseofcards-mixmaster-05b","streamable":true,"embeddable_by":"all","purchase_url":"http://www.spinninrecords.com/releases/house-of-cards","purchase_title":"Download/Stream","label_id":null,"genre":"Dance & EDM","title":"KSHMR - House of Cards (Ft. Sidnie Tipton)","description":"KSHMR and Sidnie Tipton team up again, this time for the bittersweet sound of \"House of Cards\" \n\nDownload / Stream here: https://www.spinninrecords.com/releases/house-of-cards/","label_name":null,"release":null,"track_type":null,"key_signature":null,"isrc":null,"video_url":null,"bpm":null,"release_year":null,"release_month":null,"release_day":null,"original_format":"wav","license":"all-rights-reserved","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/399448641","user":{"id":319295181,"kind":"user","permalink":"dharmaworldwide","username":"Dharma Worldwide","last_modified":"2018/03/09 12:08:27 +0000","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/users/319295181","permalink_url":"http://soundcloud.com/dharmaworldwide","avatar_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000324744374-jdrkyv-large.jpg"},"permalink_url":"https://soundcloud.com/dharmaworldwide/houseofcards-mixmaster-05b","artwork_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000302088414-recq7g-large.jpg","stream_url":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/399448641/stream","download_url":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/399448641/download","playback_count":135077,"download_count":0,"favoritings_count":7351,"reposts_count":1354,"comment_count":120,"downloadable":false,"waveform_url":"https://w1.sndcdn.com/0Bcy6WpC8dzY_m.png","attachments_uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/399448641/attachments","policy":"ALLOW","monetization_model":"NOT_APPLICABLE"}
```

I can't use `gson.fromJson(...)` method, how could I fix this?

Ps-I have pretty much changed my code.

Comment: I think you should see step 8 here; https://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/

Comment: I'm using retrofit

Comment: And gson library too, your example is on volly and java json parsing method :(

Comment: Sorry I knew but if you’re not flexible with changing libraries, it’s fine.

Comment: No, I'm beginner but thanks btw :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do:

### EDIT:

**ScService.java**

```
public interface SCService
{
    @GET("users/17586135/tracks?client_id=iZIs9mchVcX5lhVRyQGGAYlNPVldzAoX")
    Call<Track> getTrack();
}
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
Call<Track> call = Scservice.getTracks();
call.enqueue(new Callback<Track>(){

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response<Track> response)
        {
            // Get the result
            Track track = response.body();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call p1, Throwable p2)
        {
            // TODO: Implement this method
        }
    });
}
```

More [here](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/getting-started-with-retrofit-2/)

Comment: Json response is not array it's object, question updated :)

Comment: Remove `List` everywhere as it's only one Track object (and rename your method from `getTracks` to `getTrack` as you are not getting a list so it's confusing

Comment: Got this error Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: I can't use response.body() as i have to pass string as a parameter and if i pass it's showing me error

Comment: No you need to replace your `call.enqueue(new Callback<Track>()` implementation by the one I've written above. You don't need to create a Gson object in the `onResponse`

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked, but i don't understand how gson deserialize json without object?

Comment: When you do `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` you tell Retrofit to use Gson to convert the Json returned by the call. You specify the object you want in your service `Call<Track> getTrack();` then in the `onResponse` you get the object in the body of the response itself as the Json has been automatically converted.

Answer (score 0):

The Gson object should be used in this way:

```
gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Track track = gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(),Track.class);
```

Comment: Got this errorExpected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: I have updated the question, can u tell me where is the mistake